# How do I classify an isolated singularity such that every sequence converging to it has a subsequence with $f(z_{r_n})\to 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function in the punctured disc $D_R(z_0)-\{z_0\}$. Suppose that every sequence $\{z_n\}$ in $D_R(z_0)-\{z_0\}$ with $z_n \to z_o$ has a subsequence $\{z_{r_n}\}$ such that $f(z_{r_n})\to 0$. Classify the isolated singularity at $z_0$.

I could only find that it couldn't be a pole as $|f(z_0)|$ would not tend to infinity as $z_n \to z_0$.

Comment: There are three types of singularity; you excluded one, just try to exclude another one in a similar way and you are done. (Note that the singularity certainly could be removable.)

Comment: Can you say that since there because for every sequence that will converge to $z_0$ $f(z_n)$ can only converge to 0 it cannot be an essential singularity by Casorati Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: Yes, it cannot be an essential singularity. Using the result you mention you can show for example that there would be a sequence $z_n$ converging to $z_0$ such that $f(z_n)$ would converge to something other than $0$, violating the assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Viewed one way, this problem has little to do with complex analysis. The following is true on the real line, complex plane, or any metric  space:

> If every sequence $x_n$  converging  to $a$  (with $x_n\ne a$) has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $f(x_{n_k})\to 0$, then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=0$.

The proof is by contrapositive. If the  conclusion fails, there is $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $n$ there is $x_n$ with $0<|x_n-a|<1/n$ and $|f(x_n)|\ge \epsilon$. The sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $a$, and has no subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $f(x_{n_k})\to 0$.